# Using Cro run for rebuilding changed client side files

Tags: raku, cro

`cro run` stops the server, recompiles, restarts the server when anything in the directory tree changes. That's great.

But when developing the client side UI, and using NPX/yarn/webpack, there is an additional step that is needed to produce the `main.js` file.

In the Cro tutorial this step seems to be done manually, viz., we have the line *"And there we have it. `npm run build`, refresh, and give it a spin."* Here *`npm run build`* is a command that has to be run 'manually'.

Is there a simple way, eg., using `.cro.yml` to force another command when changes in a sub-directory tree are detected? Eg, if the client side UI files are under `path/to/cro-app/client-ui-directory` and the command to be run if any files change is `path/to/cro-app/client-ui/directory/yarn build`

Answer (score 0):

The cro-tools repo has all the file watching code associated with `cro run`.

So, one way would be to subclass the appropriate stuff in that repo and make a `super-cro run` command.

But I think the thing to do would be to set up a file watcher and trigger the rebuild in your server process.  Cro files set environment variables, so you could use them to configure this behavior.

Comment: I don't understand the code well enough to give write you a sample, and don't have time to figure it out right now.  But the Cro::Tools repo on github has some examples you can use as a starting point.  https://github.com/croservices/cro/blob/master/lib/Cro/Tools/Services.pm6#L121